# Eclipse ADT - "Android Common XML Editor" doesn't add new items

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, editor

I have Eclipse 4.2 with the ADT-version 23.0.2. For example if I create a new menu.xml-file and try to add some elements via the "Android Common XML Editor" I have the behavior seen in the link. There are already three items, but they are not shown inside the viewer. Also I have no choices in the "Create-Window". If I did this the first time it works. But now I can only add new items by the Text-Editor. Also if I add new Strings at the "Android Common XML Editor" it doen't work as expected and I have to use the Text-Editor. Does anybody knows a solution to work correct with the "Android Common XML Editor"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove api level 20 (Android 4.4W.2)